Error when upgrading the nebular version from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0
{ email: { service: NbDummyAuthStrategy, config: { delay: 3000, login: { rememberMe: true, }, }, }, }
I have this settings in my nbDummyAuthProviders, but after upgrading I should change to
but I am not sure how add the rememberMe in the login of config object in this new
`NbDummyAuthStrategy.setup({name:'email', delay:3000,}),`

And Also I am gettings error on mixins not sure why
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss
Module build failed: 
  @include nb-auth-global();
          ^
      No mixin named nb-auth-global

Backtrace:
        stdin:30, in mixin `@content`
        node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/_globals.scss:18, in mixin `@content`
        node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/_theming.scss:169, in mixin `nb-install-global`
        node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/_globals.scss:17, in mixin `nb-install`
        stdin:26
      in C:\ALPHA_2\ALPHA\src\app\@theme\styles\styles.scss (line 30, column 12)

let me know what I am missing in here, Thanks in Advance.
